# jquery trigger event on a bind element

Tags: javascript, jquery

post update to show actual code being used, also one of the comments was public is not valid in jquery, if so i should just drop public when creating functions?

I have a simple viewing page that consists of a master and a number of detail records.

the script looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
initialise();

    $("#order_list").on("dblclick",".show_order",function(){

    alert('click event initiated for show_order');

    });

    function initialise(){

    $('#order_list').empty();
    $('#drop_list').empty();
    $('#info').empty();

    var drop_id = "<?php echo $this_drop ?>";

    $.post('<?php echo site_url("schedules/get_drop");?>',{'drop_id':drop_id},
    function(response){
        $.each(response,function(key,val){
            drop_info = '';
            drop_info += 'DROP ID: ' + val.drop_id + '</br>';
            drop_info += 'DELIVERY POINT: '+val.destination + '</br>';
            drop_info += 'NO OF ORDERS: ' + val.noOfOrders + '       ' + 'ESTIMATED WEIGHT: ' + val.weight + '        ' + ' ESTIMATED TRAVEL DISTANCE: '+ parseFloat(val.distance)+ ' KM';
        $('#drop_info').empty();
        $('#drop_info').append(drop_info);      
        });

    },'json');

    //populate matching order info
    $.post("<?php echo site_url('schedules/get_drop_orders');?>",{'drop_id':drop_id},
    function(data){
        $.each(data,function(key,val){
            content = '';
            content += "<div class='show_order' id='"+val.order_id+"' data-weight='"+val.est_weight+"' data-qty='"+val.qty+"' data-distance='"+val.est_distance+"' data-origin='"+val.s1lat+','+val.s1lon+"' data-destination='"+val.s2lat+','+val.s2lon+"'>";
            content += "<a href='#' id='"+val.order_id+"'> Order No: "+val.order_id+"</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Collection Date: "+val.req_col_time.substr(0,10)+"</br>";
            content += "Collection Point: <a href='#' id='"+val.site1id+"'>"+val.collection+"</a></br>";
            content += "Delivery Point: <a href='#' id='"+val.site2id+"'>"+val.destination+"</a></br>";
            content += "</div>";

            $('#order_list').append(content);               
            });

    },'json');//end of post loop

    $("#order_list").trigger("dblclick");
}

});
</script>
```

playing with this i can get the click to trigger on the appended elements but i cannot get the click to trigger from the initialize event for some reason

Comment: There is no public function in javascript, that's a syntax error

Comment: content += `"<div class='show_order' ... </div>"` Observe quotes

Answer (score 3):

it is because the event handler is added after the event is triggered

```
$(document).on('click', '.show_order', function () {
    console.log('i was clicked', this);
});
//call the initialise function to populate the info through ajax calls
initialise();

function initialise() {
    var content = '';
    content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 1</div>';
    content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 2</div>';
    content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 3</div>';
    $('body').append(content);
    $('.show_order').trigger('click');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YML7S/)

In this case you need to use event delegation because when the event handler is registered the target elements are not yet added to the dom

Comment: commons guys the solution which used `setTimeout()` got 2 upvotes where this got a downvote after being the first to solve it

Comment: so far the trigger is getting fired off thank you all, problem now stands that it must only fire once on the initialise and not for every element appended

Comment: @TerenceBruwer after initializing for which element it has to be fired

Comment: @TerenceBruwer out of all the newly added elements for which one you want to trigger the event

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //call the initialise function to populate the info through ajax calls
    initialise();

    function initialise() {
        var content = '';
        content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 1</div>';
        content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 2</div>';
        content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 3</div>';

        $('body').append(content);
        $('body').on('click','.show_order',function(){
            alert('i was clicked');                   
        });
        $('.show_order').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YML7S/27/)

Comment: the question is why `$('.show_order').trigger('click');` is not working

Comment: that is entirely different from your initial answer.... I was saying your initial answer was wrong - it was nowhere close to an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    initialise();
function initialise(){

  content = '';
  content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 1</div>';
  content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 2</div>';
  content += '<div class="show_order" id="dynamically generated">item 3</div>';

  $('body').append(content);
  $(document).on('click','.show_order',function(){
   alert('i was clicked');
  });
  $('.show_order').trigger('click');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jhuTB/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YML7S/10/)**

```
$('body').on('click', '.show_order', function () {
    alert('i was clicked');
});
initialise();
```

Comment: i ran the fiddle the trigger gets fired for every element appended sorry

Comment: that because $('.show_order') will get three element,so three event are fired

Answer (score 0):

Give some timeout to the initialize function so that before the function is called, the dom is loaded and the click event is bind to the element

[Check Out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3F9u/15/)

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout(function(){initialise();},100);

$('body').on('click','.show_order',function(){    

alert('i was clicked');
});

function initialise(){

content = '';
content += "<div class='show_order' id='dynamically generated'>item 1</div>";
content += "<div class='show_order' id='dynamically generated'>item 2</div>";
content += "<div class='show_order' id='dynamically generated'>item 3</div>";

$('body').append(content);

$('.show_order').trigger('click');
}

});
```